# Hide a div on desktop

Tags: css, mobile, drop-down-menu, menu, flexbox

I am attempting to hide a div on a desktop.  I've attempted media queries (Caroline's solution here is an example: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/display-content-on-mobile-or-desktop-only-211885)

I have gotten my bigger nav (.menu) to be hidden on mobile, but I can't figure out how to hide my mobilenav on desktop.  If I set display of mobilenav to "hidden" in main CSS and display to "block" in my media query the div stays hidden.  I'm guessing there is a problem with my code somewhere.  Any advice you have would be appreciated.  Here's my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/eamr662L/ (full code for website)

Here's an excerpt of what I think is the relevant code:

```
    mobilenav {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        background-color: #000000;
        text-align: center;
    }

    mobilenav div {
        width: 100%;
    }

    mobilenav a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    mobilenav a:hover {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    mobilenav > nav > ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }

    mobilenav > nav > ul:hover {
        background-color: #000000;    
    }

    mobilenav > nav > ul > li {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        transition: all linear 0.1s;    
    }

    mobilenav > nav > ul > li a + div {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    }

    mobilenav > nav > ul > li:hover a + div {
        display: block;
        background-color: #000000;
    }

    mobilenav > nav > ul > li a + div > ul {
        list-style-type: none;  
    }

    mobilenav > nav > ul > li a + div > ul > li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    mobilenav > nav > ul > li a + div > ul > li > a {
        display: block; 
        padding: .25rem 1.5rem;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    mobilenav > nav > ul > li > a {
        align-items: flex-start;
        display: flex;
        padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

<mobilenav>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <div>Navigation</div>
                </a>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="">Research</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Ask a Librarian</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Archives &amp; Special Collections</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Exhibitions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Plant Information</a></li>                   
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</mobilenav>
```

Here's the site:

http://nybg.beta.libguides.com/

Thank you!

---

Comment: You should show your media queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason it seems that your mobilenav has `display` set to `block` on desktop. You can use `display: none;` with a media query for desktop like this:

```
@media(min-width: 601px) {
  mobilenav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Or just set the mobilenav to `display: none;` on desktop and use a media query for mobile to set the `display` to `block` on mobile:

```
mobilenav{
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 600px){
  mobilenav{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

The working **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/eamr662L/3/)**.

Maybe you should have the same menu both for desktop and mobile, and style differently using media queries.

Also, I would suggest you to put the css in an external file, not like you have now on your website between `<style></style>`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  If I want to apply javascript on the desktop version of the menu, but not on the mobile version, would I still use the same html?  I had it as one menu initially, but I don't know much javascript yet and this was proving a challenge for me.

Comment: And I will put my css in a separate file--thank you!

Comment: @EstherMarie, it should usually be the same HTML code, it really depends on what you are trying to do. You don't need javascript in this situation. You use media queries, you can read more about them here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries, also there are a lot more informations you can find on Google. Also, if you consider that my answer helped you, please don't forget to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  I have accepted.  I want to use javascript to make the menu sticky on a desktop, like you see on this site: http://www.nybg.org/science-new/  I know there is a way to have this work only on desktop, but I don't think I use media queries--I have to be more comfortable modifying the js code.

Comment: @EstherMarie, no need for javascript in your case, I see you use Bootstrap. You can use again a media query like `@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .affix {
        position: static;
    }
}` to disable the sticky navbar on mobile. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Interesting... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding media querys:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { mobilenav {display:block;} }
@media (min-width: 1199px) { mobilenav {display:none;} }
```

[Media querys example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)